# Wiring 3 50w LED Chips Off a 12v Battery

Tags: led, wiring

I have 3 of the following chips: 50w, 12v chips ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B081QBC9MZ?ref=ppx_pt2_mob_b_prod_image](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081QBC9MZ)) with the following specs:
Features & details
Current: 3750mA
Voltage: DC12-14V
Color temperature:3000-3500K Luminous flux:3500-4000LM
Lifespan:50000h

I want to wire them to a sealed 12v battery onboard my kayak.

What would’ve the best way to wire them? Series, parallel...how many amp battery should I purchase?

Comment: how would you connect one?

Comment: In series even 2 you will not have enough voltage, you have to connect them in parallel. I cannot size the battery, I do not know how long you want it to operate. You are using 11.25 amp hours, from that you can select your battery. Check the discharge rating of the battery, you cannot use 100% of the energy stored in it.

Answer (score 4):

Those are meant to be driven by a constant current driver, so do not directly apply 12v to them. Instead select a 12v input constant current LED driver that can supply no more then 3.75A and has a voltage range that includes 12-14v. You will need a heatsink.

For longer lifespan and given that those look to be very cheap, I would stay around 2A or less.

Comment: These will be housed in a full aluminum enclosing.  Does such a constant driver exist?  I’m trying to find one with those specs: input: dc12v,  output: dc12v,  amps: <3.75

Comment: Will one of these work? https://www.ledsupply.com/led-drivers/mean-well-ldd-h-series-cc-step-down-mode?gclid=CjwKCAjwkN6EBhBNEiwADVfya4pzHdQKbNs0vAoQk9z5HH2owN2JktTPP2qWeQ-lZ4BGcGJH6hyA5BoCgfwQAvD_BwE

Comment: No that will not work because it cannot output a higher voltage than the input voltage. Look for a boost rather than buck driver.

Comment: That COB LEDs have some current stabilization on board. Should be connected straight to voltage source

Comment: So would I be safe to connect 3 COBs in parallel to a 12v  12ah battery or I still need to try to find a constant current driver?

Comment: The COBs you linked don't have any current limiting. If yours are different edit your question.

Comment: Sorry...was responding to the previous comment. I’m trying to understand what you are telling me to get still.  Are you stating to arrange in series and get a boost from 12v to 36v?

Comment: Or you can suggest where I can find 50w COB with stabilization onboard :)

Comment: @user3310766 You can also get constant voltage COBs. Usually they run at higher voltage and lower current in order to keep resistor losses low, so you may not be able to get the same specs.

Comment: The 12v is the limiting factor for me....I’m building a light similar to what is seen here and runs of 12v 9ah: https://afishnsealights.com/collections/batteries/products/complete-double-trouble-combo

Comment: I’m not married to the chips I linked...just trying to build a similar setup and I know these units plug right into the battery so I’m assuming no driver

Comment: Ok will this work...boosting the 12v to 36v for the LEDs connected in series??  If so what ah 12v battery should I get and how long should I expect it to last? : https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-Boost-Step-up-Converter-Constant-Current-12V-24V-36V-48V-Power-Supply-Module-/192185650065?_trksid=p2349624.m46890.l49286

Answer (score 4):

Since the LEDs are rated for 12 volts, you must connect them in parallel to your 12 volt battery.  Since they are rated to draw almost 4 amps each, the battery must be rated to deliver at least 12 amps for the time you want to run the lights.

Comment: Those COBs are just diodes in series with a total forward voltage of 12-14v, so if he puts them in parallel with a 12v battery he will most likely either burn them out or damage the battery.

Comment: I will be carrying all this in a kayak...the leds pictured in the link attached below are 12v and no booster...thinking they must run parallel and perhaps counting on being submerged in water to keep heat down?  Just trying to understand how this is even achievable given the comments?? https://afishnsealights.com/collections/batteries/products/complete-double-trouble-combo